# windows emulator 10.0.10240 fails to start despite meeting the hardware and software specification

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

My Laptop hardware and software both are compliant for windows phone emulator .  OS is windows 10 Enterprise edition, i7 processor with 8 GB Ram SLAT compliant. Hyper v is running on the laptop . IDE used is Visual studio 2015 installed from the iso. However the emulator fails to initialise with this Msg -

'mobile emulator synthetic 3D display controller: failed to power on with error the virtual machine cannot be started because the file rdvgm.exe that is required to start the remoteFx manager does not exist.

The laptop has dual graphics intel HD graphics and nvidia GT 650M . The requirement of remoteFX manager on a client Hyper V is not understood . No amount of reinstallation of visual studio and hyper V has helped. strangely the windows 10 SDK that ships with visual studio 2015 is 10.0.10240 which fails repeatedly on installation. Standalone SDK available on the site is ver 10.0.26624 which eventualy i had to install .Looks like the IDE refuses to ack the standalone SDK . Not able to use the emulator . Any one any pointers to resolving the issue. sorry cannot post images as restricted by forum